# wondering what "the goods' means in this sentence

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I looked in the dic but hard to figure out the meaning of the "the goods" in this sentence. Thanks in advance.

The idea that justice in allocating access to a university has something to do with **the goods** that universities properly pursue explains why selling admission is unjust.

Comment: goods are goods... - *items for sale, or possessions that can be moved*

Comment: If this case, I don't think that they are. This is a non-standard usage, I think.

Comment: So what does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

**This is a relatively non-standard usage.** Normally, "the goods" refers to merchandise in some fashion, or to other items that are analogous to them (e.g. items whose delivery has been promised, illicit contraband, and the like).

In this case, I believe that the author was referring to the social benefits and good works that the university seeks to accomplish through their educational activities, and constructed this word by pluralizing "good".

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation...I really appreciate it.